# Difficulty translating postgres regular expression into php preg_match

Tags: php, postgresql

I am working on a database trying to get those rows that match the condition: begin with integer / AONO / any string / end with a year (integer). Examples of such rows include:

1. 005/AONO/CAN1er/2017
2. 167/AONO/MINEE/CMPM/2017
3. 004/AONO/DDMAPL/CDPM/2017
4. 002/AONO/CAY6/CIPM/2017
5. 004/AONO/DRMAP/DDMAP/CDPM/SM/2017

In postgres, I used the following condition in my query:

```
where reference_consultation ~* '^([0-9]*)+[/]AONO[/].*[/]([0-9]*)+$'.
```

The query works, but when trying to have the condition in php using preg_match as though:

```
if (preg_match('/^([0-9]*)+[/]AONO[/].*[/]([0-9]*)+$/',$reference)) {

        return true;
        }
else 
       return false;
```

even for matching references I get false

Comment: You should escape your delimiters or use different ones. Another problem could be with your quantifiers: Use `([0-9]+)` instead of `([0-9]*)+` if you want to grab anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_match('/^([0-9]*)+[/]AONO[/].*[/]([0-9]*)+$/', $reference)`

You are using `/` as your delimter, yet using it in the regex too.

You need to either escape them within the regex

`preg_match('/^([0-9]*)+[\/]AONO[\/].*[\/]([0-9]*)+$/', $reference)`

Or use different delimiters

`preg_match('~^([0-9]*)+[/]AONO[/].*[/]([0-9]*)+$~', $reference)`